# Weber function takes on real values?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, modular-forms

Why does the Weber function take on real values? In the middle of the proof, the author argues... "cleary it is real-valued." I don't follow the argument. Info about the Weber function $\mathfrak{f}_1$ is given at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_modular_function

What about the general case, and what if $\tau=\sqrt{-14}$?

Comment: I originally forgot about the factor $q^{-1/48}$ resp. $q^{1/24}$. These are only real when the real part of $\tau$ is a multiple of $24$ resp. $12$. So the values are not real when $\operatorname{Re}\tau = 5$ for example, but they are of course for purely imaginary $\tau$. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, as non-constant holomorphic functions, the Weber functions are not real-valued. However, the infinite products in the Weber functions take real values (at least) when $q = e^{2\pi i\tau}$ is a positive real number, which is the case whenever $\operatorname{Re} \tau \in \mathbb{Z}$, and and the functions themselves when the lone factor $q^{-1/48} = e^{-\pi i\tau/24}$ for $\mathfrak{f}$ and $\mathfrak{f}_1$ resp. $q^{1/24} = e^{\pi i\tau/12}$ for $\mathfrak{f}_2$ is also real, which is the case for $\operatorname{Re}\tau \in 24\mathbb{Z}$, resp.  $\operatorname{Re}\tau \in 12\mathbb{Z}$ (they may also take real values for some values of $\tau$ with non-integral real part). In particular, for the purely imaginary $\tau = \sqrt{-14}$, all three Weber functions take a real value.